# Scripts.Render is not working

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I'm developing ASP.NET MVC Razor project using monodevelop 5.9.6 and I added all packages necessary for bundling (`System.Web.Optimization`), in `BundleConfig` I'm adding

```
bundles.add(ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

and others. In `Global.asax.cs` I'm calling

```
 BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.bundles);
```

However in `_Layout.cshtml`

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

is rendering as

```
<script src="/bundle/jquery?v=5GM9HLcujnDGm6SNVq0Es63_cXK2viQ4_nYEpm02Ls1"></script>
```

when running, causing `"Failed to load resource (404)"` javascript error, because all jquery's files are not rendered as it should be.

I need to render all jquery files and style files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a feature of Bundling and Minification. All of jquery and css file grouped into one file when you enable Bundling and Minification and it works in two conditions

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  //Enabling Bundling and Minification
  BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;  
}

<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
```

IF you want each file render separately use 
**compilation debug = "true"** and 
**BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;**.

But it's not a good practice when deploying code to production server.

Why 404 : If you can share your rendering code for jquery and css file I can try why 404 error is coming.`enter code here`

Thanks

Comment: cache.net thanks! it worked perfectly, however before fix it, I taked source code from html: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="/bundles/jquery?v=gGGRI7xCOnEK-4qvkXXwhmbyGmA8S3tmz-Wto5bGsIc1"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Welcome to ASP.NET MVC 5.2 on Mono!</h2>
</body>
</html>. When I use google chrome "inspect element" tool I see the error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)", pointing to "/bundles/jquery?v=gGGRI7xCOnEK-4qvkXXwhmbyGmA8S3tmz-Wto5bGsIc1", page is rendered normally.

Comment: @AldemarCuartasCarvajal this comment saved my day thanks

Comment: @AldemarCuartasCarvajal this comment saved my day thanks

Comment: Hassan Elsherbiny, glad to hear that!